# Why does a Python dataclass "persist" outside the scope of its defining function?

Tags: python, scope, python-dataclasses

Consider the following minimal example:

```
>>> from dataclasses import dataclass
>>> @dataclass
... class my_stuff:
...     my_variable: int = 0
...
>>> def my_func():
...     stuff = my_stuff
...     stuff.my_variable += 1
...     print(stuff.my_variable)
...
>>> my_func()
1
>>> my_func()
2
>>> my_func()
3
```

Why does the printed value increase with each call to `my_func()`? Should `stuff` not go out of scope once the execution of `my_func()` is complete? And should each call to `my_func()` not create a new instance with `my_variable` initialized to 0 and incremented to 1 each time?

How would I change this code to meet my (apparently irrational) expectation that 1 would be output each time `my_func()` is called?

Comment: Try replacing stuff = my_stuff by stuff = my_stuff() to instantiate a new object every time instead of modifying the class itself.

Comment: `stuff.my_variable` where `stuff=my_stuff`  modifies the class attribute value. I.e. your code is working as expected, and your expectation/assumption of something different is irrational.

Comment: To debug this sort of problem, in this case print `stuff` In the function; you’ll see it is the class defintion.

Comment: `stuff` is just another name for `my_stuff`.  One name going out of scope does not affect the object itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You are using Class itself Rather than instance!

```
class human:
    pass


human_kind = human #Pointer to class

print(human_kind)

alex = human() #Instance initializing

print(alex)
```

> Results:
>
> <class '**main**.human'>
>
> <**main**.human object at 0x7fd11ce47100>

true code:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class my_stuff:
    my_variable: int = 0


def my_func():
    stuff = my_stuff()
    stuff.my_variable += 1
    print(stuff.my_variable)
```